# Filter input layers to point layers

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

Can I edit this code below to show only point layers?

This is being used in a Plugin for QGIS 2.

I am creating if that makes any difference.

```
self.addParameter(ParameterVector(self.INPUT, self.tr('Input layer'), [ParameterVector.VECTOR_TYPE_ANY]))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Answer for QGIS 2.18**

You can according to the QGIS code base by using `ParameterVector.VECTOR_TYPE_POINT` instead of `ParameterVector.VECTOR_TYPE_ANY`. You need to do import using `from processing.core.parameters import ParameterVector`

Info extracted from QGIS 2.18 code base file https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/ltr-2_18/python/plugins/processing/script/ScriptAlgorithm.py#L203

For **QGIS 3.x**, it should be

```py
# At the top of your file
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing

self.addParameter(
    QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
        self.INPUT,
        self.tr('Input layer'),
        [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint]
    )
)
```

The enum for other types of geometry for QGIS 3 can be seen in https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessing.html#acad4d2322342455b53eee5701e2b3115

Comment: That's what I thought but still not working.  Tried LINE and POLYGON.  It's not filtering so I guess there is an issue with my "bindings"?  I am using Qgs Widgets in QT designer, renamed the map layer combo box to INPUT but always get all layers?

Comment: Normal, you are mixing things. The "map layer combo box" is using the class `QgsMapLayerComboBox`. If you want to filter, you have to set filters like at https://webgeodatavore.github.io/pyqgis-samples/gui-group/QgsMapLayerComboBox.html You will need to replace in the sample, the line `map_layer_combo_box.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.VectorLayer)` with `map_layer_combo_box.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.PointLayer)`.
The sample code you mentioned is for processing algorithms

Comment: Thx Thomas, yea I was also creating a script based on that method as well.  Seems if I go the Parameter route I get the errors like above and if go Qgs route I get unrecognized module errors?  So I have been battling this for many weeks with no success.  Should anyone care to help set me straight via Skype would much appreciated...socalclutch@gmail.com.